# Open app automatically after i manually update it from within the app

Tags: android

So i have an app that once opened it checks with the server if there is a newer version and if yes it downloads it and installs it.

Now i want the app to open automatically after the update is installed because now it installs and than stays at the device's home screen.

The code i use to install after i have downloaded the apk file.

```
private void installApkToDevice(Uri uri, int key) {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    install.setDataAndType(uri,
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(install, key);
}
```

Comment: open app by package name.

Comment: doesn't it show open button when package installer complete the installation?

Comment: @jubayer Nope it does not

Comment: are you downloading the apk using DownloadManager?

Comment: I'm indeed @jubayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` intent.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Start your activity from MyBroadcastReceiver